# Is the Range property in Java for HttpURLConnections inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: java, networking, range, httpconnection

I am grabbing objects from online using Range like so:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=0-1000");

// Parallel in different thread

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=1000-2000");

// More code that actually collects the data
```

Is this grabbing the 1000th byte twice? Or is the upper bound exclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positions are inclusive.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-2.1

> The first-byte-pos value in a byte-range-spec gives the byte-offset of the first byte in a range.
> The last-byte-pos value gives the byte-offset of the last byte in the range;
> that is, the byte positions specified are inclusive. Byte offsets start at zero.